# Can I get terminal title? (or otherwise restore old one)

Tags: terminal, xterm

Setting terminal title is easy with `echo -e "\e]0;some title\007"`. Works with pretty much every terminal program.

What I want is to set terminal title when some program starts - and restore old one when it finishes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some terminal programs that supporting it (xterm has compile time options for that, as mentioned by RWS), but most terminal programs simply lack such feature, including in particular Terminal.app.

Comment: For Terminal.app, AppleScript to the rescue: `title=\`osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to  get name of front window'\`` and then `echo $title` works just as expected. Not too nice to need AppleScript though.

Comment: (And using AppleScript like above only works nicely if you only have a single Terminal window, or if it's indeed the frontmost window...)

Answer (score 11):

On xterm, the [terminal control sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) 22 and 23 work fine, as in

```sh
#!/bin/sh
/bin/echo -ne '\033[22;0t'  # Save title on stack
/bin/echo -ne "\033]0;$(date)\007"
sleep 1
/bin/echo -ne '\033[23;0t'  # Restore title from stack
```

It looks like this isn't supported in the Mac OS X Terminal.App though.

Comment: It have tested Konsole 1.6.4 and Gnome Terminal 2.16.10 (both very, very old, I have to admit, but nice to know if you want to go for compatibility). Result: It does not work.

Comment: Also not working with roxterm (probably other VTE based terminals?)

Comment: [Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty) 0.7.2 (5ac8060b) works.

Comment: Works in tmux. [st](http://st.suckless.org/) seems to have a [patch](http://st.suckless.org/patches/csi_22_23/) for this.

Comment: Works with Gnome Terminal 3.40.3, but not on Konsole 21.08.2

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to set the window title during my script, then unset the window title when I completed. Unsetting the title reverted to the original value. Specifically, I did the following:

```
# Set the terminal title
printf "\e]2;%s\a" "running my script"
# Do whatever processing is required.
...

# Restore terminal title
printf "\e]2;\a"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible indeed. See a `xterm` reference manual (like [this](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) for example) and wander your way through it. `xterm` even has a build in stack for this, so you don't have to store the title manually.