# System.Console.ANSI in Haskell, Reset Terminal Title.

Tags: haskell

I am using System.Console.ANSI in my Haskell program to set the terminal title, but when my program exits the title of the terminal is persistent.

I can only assume this would be a slight annoyance to those using my program who wish to work on something else in the same terminal.

I can cheat and reset it to 'Terminal' but that is under the assumption that the terminal used, is by default called 'Terminal' which I know is not always the case.

I am wondering if there is a way of setting or resetting the title when the user selects to quit my program?

Comment: I can't imagine why this question is getting down/close votes. This is something I've wondered a lot of times myself. Moreover, as a current maintainer of said module, I'd gladly accept a pull request implementing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some terminals support a "stack" of titles and a way to restore the title to a previously set title.

Some links:

- [Can I get terminal title? (or otherwise restore old one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232655/can-i-get-terminal-title-or-otherwise-restore-old-one)
- https://superuser.com/questions/339862/restore-mac-os-x-terminal-title-after-closing-a-ssh-connection

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, it is not a perfect solution but my final code was: `callCommand "printf '\\e]0;\\a'"`, I then had to do a `clearScreen` otherwise it leaves half the printf command before the prompt and then it exits the program.